# Finding strings in a file and write to a file if found

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Just wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. I want to search a file for 2 strings and if they match add a YES to a csv file or NO if they don't. For now tough I'd like to just have it find the strings and print SUCCESS on the screen if found as per below (I'd rather try get the writing to a file done myself so I learn).

I do need both strings to be a match otherwise the result should be No.

I've gotten this so far:

```
#/usr/bin/bash
file=test.xml
string1=TEST1
string2=TEST2
if grep -e "$string1|$string2" "$file"
then
    echo IT WORKS!!!
else
    echo UH OH!!!
fi
```

Comment: Do you want `YES` if both strings appear, or if either one appears?

Comment: I require both strings to be a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that either string matching is sufficient, try this:

```
file=test.xml
string1="TEST1"
string2="TEST2"

if grep -q -F "$string1"$'\n'"$string2" "$file" ; then
    printf YES
else
    printf NO
fi
```

Importantly, `-F` means that if the string happens to contain regex-special characters they will be treated literally. For convenience `-q` will suppress the output of `grep` so you only get the YES/NO returned.

EDIT:

Since you need both strings to match, try this:

```
if [ $(sed -n -e "/${string1}/p;/${string2}/p" "$file" | wc -l) -ge 2 ] ; then
    printf YES
else
    printf NO
fi
```

This is not as safe as the `grep` version since regex characters in the strings are not treated literally and is rather inefficient, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I do however need both strings to be a match. I'll update the question also.

Comment: This works it is printing YES or NO before the prompt but ill be changing it to a file anyway

Comment: @ShellNewbie: I deliberately left a newline out of the print so that redirecting output to a file would not cause extra lines to be added.

Comment: @ShellNewbie: Technically there's a bug in this even still: If you have `TEST1` twice it will still print `YES` even with no `TEST2`; here's a perl oneliner that doesn't have that problem: `perl -e 'while(my $l=<STDIN>){foreach my$s(@ARGV){if($l=~/$s/){$seen{$s}++;}}}END{scalar keys%seen>=2&&{print "YES"}||print "NO"}' < "$file" "$string1" "$string2"`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want both strings to match, an inefficient way is to call `grep` once for each pattern:

```
if grep -q "$string1" && grep -q "$string2"
then
echo IT WORKS
else
echo UH OH
fi
```

I'm not aware of a way to do this with a single grep call without a fairly complicated regex. Something like

```
grep -qE "$string1.*$string2|$string2.*$string1"
```

could work, but I'm sure that would include some false positives and/or false negatives, depending on the values of `string1` and `string2`.

Comment: The complicated regex only works when both matches are on the same line.

Comment: The strings will be on seperate lines basically the start and end of the file

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` you would need to read the file twice:

```
if grep "$string1" "$file" && grep "$string2" "$file"
```

However, using AWK, you can set flags and you'll only need to read the file once:

```
awk -v s1="$string1" -v s2="$string2" '$0 ~ s1 {f1 = 1} $0 ~ s2 {f2 = 1} END {if (f1 && f2) {print "Yes"} else {print "No"}}' "$file"
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try and figure our writing this to a file next, I suppose I should change the output from the screen to a file and go from there.

Comment: It looks right, but in testing I get Yes even when one of the strings is absent.

Comment: This code seems to be happy once it finds TEST1 or TEST2,. I need to to match both, I'll see how I get on changing it.

Comment: @ShellNewbie: It does test for the presence of both in the file. How is it not working for you?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I know it looks like it does, but I tried it with a file whose contents was `TEST1` only and it still printed `Yes`. See this paste: http://pastebin.ca/2169102

Comment: @Sorpigal: That's because of a typo on my part caused by dealing with too many different languages - `and` should be `&&`.

Comment: @ShellNewbie: I fixed a typo. Please try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in the good direction. You need to change `-e` with `-E` in order for `grep` to recognize the regular expression that you are using (`$string1|$string2`). You may also want to avoid seeing the actual matchings (use quiet `-q` flag for that):

```
file=test.xml
string1="TEST1"
string2="TEST2"
if grep -E -q "$string1|$string2" "$file"
then
    echo IT WORKS!!!
else
    echo UH OH!!!
fi
```

**EDIT:** Since you need to match both strings, this is not possible with `grep` (AFAIK) unless you execute `grep` multiple times (like in @chepner's answer).

An alternative solution would be to use `awk`:

```
awk '/'$string1'/{s1=1}/'$string2'/{s2=1} END { \
    if (s1 && s2) print "IT WORKS!!!" ; else print "UH OH!!!" }' "$file"
```

Comment: For some reason when I run this I get: -bash: ./checkXML.sh: /usr/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: The shell location was wrong, it should be `/bin/bash`. In your code it works because you made a small mistake (`#/usr/bin/bash` instead of `#!/usr/bin/bash`). However, most probably `bash` is in `/bin/bash`). Still, this solution as it is will not work if you need to match both strings at the same time. Actually, I do not think that is possible with `grep` (unless both strings are on the same line).

Comment: I spotted it a momemt ago and changed it but no luck. In order to find two strings do you have any suggestions, grep isn't manditory Its just the first thing that popped into my head to use.

Comment: @ShellNewbie I have updated my answer to include a solution using `awk`.

Comment: The awk command is returning UH OH!!! regardless of weather TEST1 and TEST2 are listed in the test.xml file

Comment: @ShellNewbie There was a small error with the quotation marks. It works now for me.